# Is possible to install a module and a wrapper script using pip at once?

Tags: python, pip, publish

So far I shared my Python programs with people in this way:

1. Write a module `my_module` with functions
2. Write a wrapper script `my_script` which uses this module and additional packages like `argparse`
3. Publish `my_module` on PyPI
4. Push software to Github with a readme file explaining how to install it:

   - Install the module using `pip install my_module`
   - Download `my_script` from Github and move it to the place pointed by the `PATH` variable or run it locally by `python my_script`

This way seems to be good but I'm wondering is it possible to install it by a one-shot, i.e. `pip install my_software` which installs everything at once. Moreover, it's important to be able to call the wrapper script after installation typing just `my_script`.

What is the best recipe to publish such software?

Comment: The "scripts" argument in the call to `setup ()` is useful here.

Comment: @TylerGubala Could you put that in an answer, maybe a bit extended with an example or so? The [click example](http://click.pocoo.org/5/setuptools/#introduction) might be good enough if you don't want to write an example from scratch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Setuptools Documentation:

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

> [Specifying scripts in distutils used to be hard...] setuptools fixes
>   all of these problems by automatically generating scripts for you with
>   the correct extension, and on Windows it will even create an .exe file
>   so that users don’t have to change their PATHEXT settings. The way to
>   use this feature is to define “entry points” in your setup script that
>   indicate what function the generated script should import and run. For
>   example, to create two console scripts called foo and bar, and a GUI
>   script called baz, you might do something like this:

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = my_package.some_module:main_func',
            'bar = other_module:some_func',
        ],
        'gui_scripts': [
            'baz = my_package_gui:start_func',
        ]
    }
)
```

Please note that if the scripts are the restult of a build process that is not directly related to setuptools (you want to provide a package on pypi, but want to build using your cmake toolchain) you will need to override the `install_scripts` class from `setuptools.command.install_scripts`